# Need help adding database references to database projects using code

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-extensions

I want to develop an visual studio extension that does some automation for my sql database projects in visual studio. Among those task is adding the database references. I cannot find any way to do this from the extensions code.

I can get the proper project node retrieving ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;
and than iterating over the project in the solutions. But the project object seems to be of type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.IDatabaseProjectNode Which is marked internal and thus cannot be used by me.

Is there any official way to add database references (and do other sql database project specific things) or do I have to resort to editing the project files directly?

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fc4c077e-3199-492d-b614-4a2e4d60d572/the-right-way-to-add-a-database-reference-in-a-vs-extension?forum=ssdt) can make some help:)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT I have seen that one, the end conclusion is that with current SSDT libs it's just not possible. I had hoped something changed since 2012 on that point.

Comment: Not sure if the interfaces in [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Services Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.data.services?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) can help, I can't find any documents about this, but I'll try to confirm if this is what you want with the help with the team. It may take some time :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, Maybe those interfaces are useful, but that stuff is so badly documented I would not know where to begin looking.... If you get something back from the team love to hear it, I'm not in a rush.

Comment: I've involved someone more experienced in it to research, but It may take some time before the next reply...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the answer could be negative, after discussion with `.net` and `SQL` team, adding `database reference` is not supported for now.

Adding `database reference` is much more complex than adding normal reference(.dll), there exists no public API for this behavior in VS SDK.

Comment: Then it's about time a public API was added. Seems Microsoft is moving toward putting everything in SSDT projects. So automation should be a priority. For now I looked at what de UI did to the project file when adding manually and replicating that seems to work. But it is finicky and error prone and causes a project reload on save. Just plain silly that I have to code this out myself. Just make the existing API public instead of internal a 5 minute refactor. That said I appreciate any and all effort you made on this.

Comment: Sorry for that inconvenience, I'm not sure if the public API would be added in VS2019 SDK, maybe future versions? Since it's a meaningful idea, I suggest you can post a feature request about this issue, share the link in your question and here, we will vote for it :)